# Simple Jenkins pipeline project failing

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I want to create a package of software based on Linux. It contains the following components

```
Kernel
RootFS
CustomSoftware
```

There is a `Jenkins Job` to build each one of these components.
I also have a `Packager Job` that will create a unified package that contains all the above three.

Now I want to create a Jenkins pipeline project for `Packager` that does the following.

1) Start the Jenkins jobs `Kernel`, `RootFS` and `CustomSoftware`.
2) When all three are finished run the `Packager Job` to package up the artifacts from the above three jobs.

```
parallel(
 node {
    build job: 'My_KNL', parameters: [[$class: 'BooleanParameterValue', name: 'TAG_BUILD', value: true]]
 }
 node {
    build job: 'My_RootFS_Git', parameters: [[$class: 'BooleanParameterValue', name: 'TAG_BUILD', value: true]]
 }
 node {
    build job: 'My_Software', parameters: [[$class: 'BooleanParameterValue', name: 'TAG_BUILD', value: true]]
 }
)
```

If I just run the above jenkins file form the `Package Job` it fails with the following error.

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 5: unexpected token: node @ line 5, column 2.
    node {
    ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:120)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:132)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:350)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:144)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:234)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:168)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:943)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:131)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:560)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:521)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:330)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: You do not need to wrap build step with "node".  This has no positive effect as the build will allocate its node again matching its criteria.

Answer (score 3):

To parallel step it just needs to be a groovy dict as an argument instead of multiple `node {}`. You will not need a node block to trigger a build on another job.

Removing the node blocks and making it a groovy dict would work, i.e:

```
parallel(
  knl: {
    build job: 'My_KNL', parameters: [[$class: 'BooleanParameterValue', name: 'TAG_BUILD', value: true]]
  },
  rootFsGit: {
    build job: 'My_RootFS_Git', parameters: [[$class: 'BooleanParameterValue', name: 'TAG_BUILD', value: true]]
  },
  software: {
    build job: 'My_Software', parameters: [[$class: 'BooleanParameterValue', name: 'TAG_BUILD', value: true]]
  }
)
```

Another style could be as below with script inside a step:

```
    script {
        mydict = [:]
        mydict["My_KNL"] = {
            build job: 'My_KNL', parameters: [[$class: 'BooleanParameterValue', name: 'TAG_BUILD', value: true]]
        }
        // and so on.. for all of your jobs.
        parallel mydict
    }
```